# How to project custom intermediary content using Angular component transclusion?

Tags: angular

Is there a solution in Angular for specifying the projection of containing/intermediary content that further wraps content internal to the component that allows projection? For example, say I'd like to customise what wrapper my custom component uses to produce this final output:

```html
<my-custom-component>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>{{ titleOfCustomComponent }}</legend>
        <!-- Content internal to `my-custom-component` then rendered here -->
    </fieldset>
</my-custom-component>
```

You could imagine that in a non-form context, it may not be appropriate to use a fieldset element, so instead, perhaps a simple div is more useful:

```html
<my-custom-component>
    <div>
        <h1>{{ titleOfCustomComponent }}</h1>
        <!-- Content internal to `my-custom-component` then rendered here -->
    </div>
</my-custom-component>
```

How can I project these wrapping elements inside `my-custom-component`, while still allowing `my-custom-component` to then, inside those wrapping elements, display its own content? Normally, projected content is rendered as a leaf node inside the element, whereas I'm seeking something that projects intermediary nodes that my custom element can then use to attach its own content.

What is the best practice here? And please, before commenting:

1. I am not asking for some trivial content projection solution using `<ng-content></ng-content>`, this won't work here.
2. No, I can't just move the wrapping content outside of the custom element. The custom element may manipulate the wrapping projected content itself in any number of ways.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, but it's not flexible enough and I would use it if you got only one template to inject.

The idea is to add `<ng-template>` to projected content and use a directive to get it's `viewContainer`.

Then in `my-custom-component` you can get this viewContainer with `ContentChildren` decorator and add you dynamic content, which should be defined inside  tag.

[Here is an example of this approach](https://stackblitz.com/edit/view-content-children-j3uepf?file=app/demo.component.css)